# React Component mounting life cycle called twice react 16.13.1

Tags: reactjs

I am using react 16.13.1 and created react app using create-react-app 3.4.1.

Mounting lifecycle is being called twice for every component.

I created component FirstComponent.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class FirstComponent extends Component {
    constructor(p) {
        super(p);
        console.log("FirstComponent constructor called")
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("FirstComponent componentDidMount called")
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps() {
        console.log("FirstComponent getDerivedStateFromProps called")
        return null;
    }

    render() {
        console.log("FirstComponent render called")
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default FirstComponent;
```

and called FirstComponent from App.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import FirstComponent from "./FirstComponent";

function App() {
  useEffect(()=>console.log("App useEffect Called"));

  console.log("App called");
  return (
    <FirstComponent/>
  );
}
export default App;
```

console output: (ignoring getDerivedStateFromProps warning)

```
App called
App called
FirstComponent constructor called
FirstComponent constructor called
FirstComponent getDerivedStateFromProps called
FirstComponent getDerivedStateFromProps called
FirstComponent render called
FirstComponent render called
FirstComponent componentDidMount called
App useEffect Called
```

Comment: Does is resolve your issue if you pass an empty array as second argument for the `useEffect`? The second argument is used to add dependencies to the hook.

Comment: @Trisma useEffect has nothing to do with mounting lifecycle I used useEffect just to show only mounting lifecycle is called twice and useEffect does not belong to mounting life cycle. so adding empty array as second argument in useEffect does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because codesandbox.io runs react applications in strict mode by using `<React.StrictMode />` and in strict mode side effects are double-invoked means executed two times, if you unwrap your `<App />` component from `<React.StrictMode>` in `index.js` it'll work just fine.

Here's how docs define this:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
>   can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
>   This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
>   Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method Function
>   component bodies State updater functions (the first argument to
>   setState) Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Comment: This works but is there any other way to prevent this behavior and use React.StrictMode

Comment: side effects are double-invoked only locally, so don't worry about performance it'll work fine in production